# Calculating difference in rows for many columns in SQL (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

What's up guys. I have an other question regarding using SQL to analyze. I have a table build like this.

```
ID    Date     Value
1  31.01.2019  10
1  30.01.2019  5
2  31.01.2019  20
2  30.01.2019  10
3  31.01.2019  30
3  30.01.2019  20
```

With many different IDs and many different Dates. What I would like to have as an output is an additional column, that gives me the difference to the previous date for each ID. So that I can then analyze the change of values between days for each Category (ID). To do that I would need to avoid that the command computes the difference of `Last Day WHERE ID = 1 - First Day WHERE ID = 2`.

```
Desired Output:
ID   Date      Difference to previous Days
1  31.01.2019  5
2  31.01.2019  10
3  31.01.2019  10
```

In the end I want to find outlier, so days where the difference in value between two days is very large. Does anyone have a solution? If it is not possible with Access, I am open to solutions with Excel, but Access should be the first choice as it is more scaleable.

Greetings and thanks in advance!!

Comment: I looks like you don't have many columns but rows with repeating IDs.

Comment: Thank you. But this approach fails, if I don't have every date in my dataset, right? Because in my dataset bankholidays and Saturdays/Sundays are not included. Can you adjust the query to account for non continuous dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a self join:

```
select t1.ID, t1.[Date],
  t1.[Value] - t2.[Value] as [Difference to previous Day]
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on t2.[ID] = t1.[ID] and t2.[Date] = t1.[Date] - 1
```

Results:

```
ID  Date        Difference to previous Day
1   31/1/2019   5
2   31/1/2019   10
3   31/1/2019   10
```

Edit.
For the case that there are gaps between your dates:

```
select
  t1.ID, t1.[Date], t1.[Value] - t2.[Value] as [Difference to previous Day]
from (
  select t.ID, t.[Date], t.[Value],
    (select max(tt.[Date]) from tablename as tt where ID = t.ID and tt.[Date] < t.[Date]) as prevdate
  from tablename as t
) as t1 inner join tablename as t2
on t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.[Date] = t1.prevdate
```

Comment: @n_urb: Access' query designer does not support this kind of join (because of the date calculation, self joins are supported). Therefore in Access, you will have to switch the query to SQL view.

Comment: Thank you good Sir. I don't get an error, so the query is running through. I have 5 mil rows in the dataset though, so the runtime is very long. Will see if it works out.

Comment: @n_urb for 5 mil rows Access would struggle even for a simple `select...where...` query, so in this case things are much worse. You could try to improve by setting indexes on id and date if they don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your example data, each `id` has the same two rows and the values are increasing.  If this is generally true, then you can simply use aggregation:

```
select id, max(date), max(value) - min(value)
from t
group by id;
```

If the values might not be increasing, but the dates are the same, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(date),
       (max(iif(date = "31.01.2019", value, null)) - 
        max(iif(date = "30.01.2019", value, null)) 
       ) as diff
from t
group by id;
```

Note:  Your date looks like it is using a bespoke format, so I am just doing the comparison as a string.

If previous date is exactly one day before, you can use a `join`:

```
select t.*,
       (t.value - tprev.value) as diff
from t left join
     t as tprev
     on t.id = tprev.di and t.date = dateadd("d", 1, tprev.date);
```

If date is arbitrarily the previous date in the table, then you can use a correlated subquery

```
select t.*,
       (t.value -
        (select top (1) tprev.value
         from t as tprev
         where tprev.id = t.id and tprev.date < t.date
         order by tprev.date desc
        )
       ) as diff
       (t.value - tprev.value) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: No, the values are not always increasing, but the dates are the same. For the conditional aggregation, do I need to specify the exact date? Because this is not a possible option then as I have Timestamps going back to 2007 and I can't write every single date down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join with an additional condition using a sub-query to determine the previous date

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Date, t.Value - prev.Value AS Diff
FROM
  dtvalues AS t
  INNER JOIN dtvalues AS prev
    ON t.ID = prev.ID
WHERE
    prev.[Date] = (SELECT MAX(x.[Date]) FROM dtvalues x WHERE x.ID=t.ID AND x.[Date]<t.[Date])
ORDER BY t.ID, t.[Date];
```

You could also include the where condition into the join condition, but the query designer would not be able to handle the query anymore. Like this, you can still edit the query in the query designer.